# jquery iterate through divs and first "empty" div

Tags: jquery, css, html, each

I've got a jquery application I'm working on where users basically click on an item and it moves the item over to the `equipped` section.

How I was planning on making this work, was when a class `equippable` is clicked, jquery will look for the first child div under `#weapons` with a `data-item` value of `0` and assign it the value from the `equippable`.

To give you a better idea of what's going on, here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shantred/yJhZZ/).

I was originally going to use an each function, but that would replace both available equipment slots. I need to just be able to find the first available, or if there is not one available, send an alert and I'm not sure how to find that first available slot.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".equippable").click(function() {
        $('#weapons')
              .find('div[data-item="0"]:first') // first div with data-item=0
              .attr('data-item', $(this).data('item')); // chage data-item value
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Shantred/yJhZZ/)**

You can also do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".equippable").click(function() {
        $('div[data-item="0"]:first', '#weapons')  // first div with data-item=0
           .attr('data-item', $(this).data('item'))
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/yJhZZ/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [THIS?](http://jsfiddle.net/yJhZZ/6/) (I'm alerting the text property of the first available)

The selector you need is this:

```
$('#weapons [data-item=0]:first')
```

So to set the data property, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".equippable").click(function() {
        $('#weapons [data-item=0]:first').data("item", $(this).data("item"));
    }); 
});
```

​

Comment: no mate, your comment about my second answer. I think an excellent user like you shouldn't throw stone like blind

Comment: @thecodeparadox Yeah I just realised we actually based it off his Fiddle, got confused sorry about that lol :)

Answer (score 1):

I think simplest way to achieve this is to use additional class for weapon slots:

```
<div id="weapons">
    <div class="weapon_slot empty">No Equip</div>
    <div class="weapon_slot empty">No Equip</div>
</div>
```

and then get first empty with code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".equippable").click(function() {
        var empty_slots = $('#weapons div.weapon_slot.empty'),
            first_empty = $(empty_slots).filter(':first');

        if(first_empty.length > 0) {
            $(first_empty).removeClass('empty');
            // and whatever you also need to do here...
        }
        else { /* Place for alert here */ }
    }); 
});
```

I just updated your fiddle (sorry if this is a problem) and it works as is should - if you click on item `.empty` class in first element disappears (so every code you will add there will be executed properly on first empty element).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".equippable").click(function() {
       var $emptySlot = $('#weapons').find('.no_equipment[data-item=0]')[0]; // Get the first empty slot
        $emptySlot.find('.no_equipment[data-item=0]').append(this);
        $emptySlot.data('item') = 1;
    });
});
```

​